# GMS background crash

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

My app has recently started getting this error and giving an ANR whenever the user selects to open a maps app through my app. When you try to back out of the maps and return to my app, it's stuck on a black screen till it prompts the user to decide to kill it or wait. These are the only errors I can find in the log:

> 06-06 15:12:37.878 3283-3303/com.myapp E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
>
> 06-06 15:12:41.790 3365-3365/com.myapp:background_crash E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.crash.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]

This happens on Lollipop AND Marshmallow, and I have confirmed that the devices are up-to-date with Google Play Services.